# Логирование ajax запросов chromedriver

Tags: ajax, ruby

Есть гем browsermob-proxy в связке с har, который позволяет для chromedriver логировать все ajax запросы и ответы сервера, а затем их парсить из приятного json'a. Есть ли возможность сохранять запросы со страницы, без использования сторонних гемов, на чистом selenium webdriver или chromedriver?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под гемом?

Comment: @hedgehogues ну... гем. Так в мире Ruby [библиотеки называются](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/). Добро пожаловать в Клуб.